# Vertically Responsive background video

Tags: html, css, video

I have a simple `html` page in which i have added a background video clip and a `div` containing `h1` and a `p` element.

Background video is fully responsive horizontally if browser window is resized but it is **not responsive vertically**. When browser window is resized, video **shrinks vertically** from the bottom of the screen. **How can i make this video responsive vertically as well**?

Here's a visual representation of my problem

[image]

as you can see, video shrinks vertically from the bottom when browser window is resized. Need help fixing this issue.

Here's my code

### Relevant HTML code

```
<body>

    <div class="video-container">
        <video src="Lamp%20-%2011186.mp4" autoplay loop muted></video>
    </div>  

</body>
```

### Relevant CSS code

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.video-container{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

video{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Try using vh for height instead of % on the video

Comment: tried it, didn't help...

Comment: set the `height` on the video...?

Comment: @JeromeIndefenzo setting the height makes it unresponsive horizontally

Answer (score 0):

Modify your CSS code to this and retry. It should work. The vh makes the video responsive with the browser viewport height and it will resize to 70% of the browser height when resized.

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.video-container{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

video{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vh;
}
```

Comment: now video doesn't fits the screen width and height when browser window is maximized. Also when browser window is resized to smaller width, it moves in to middle of the browser

Comment: That was just an example for you to tweak with the video height according to your code to fit. You dont really have to use "70"

Comment: @Nick video aren't images and you can't have them being responsive with different aspect ratios. If a video is of the aspect ratio 16:9 and no matter how youve made is responsive it will never change that ratio no matter however much you shrink or expand the viewport.